# How do I get information back from paypal after the payment is approved?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I have an asp.net MVC4 action that has a subscribe paypal button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payPalForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="@item.Id">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="@item.Name">
                <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">@*Recurring until user cancels*@
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> @*Billing cycle amount*@
                <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> @*billing cycle period - Month*@
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="dude@dude.com">@*Hiva's paypal account*@
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="@returnUrl">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="@item.Price">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Subscribe">
            </form>
```

In the return URL it hits an action where I want to be able to see the form details and whether the payment went through, and all that good stuff. This is what I have:

```
        public ActionResult PaymentConfirm(FormCollection form)
    {
        //if successful, blah blah
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
        //Merchant merch = ctx.Merchants.Single(x => x.User.UserName == user);
        //merch.Plan = plan;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Merchant");
    }
```

How can I get this data!

Comment: Check out PayPal IPN? https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: I don't have the info on hand, but the IPN Docs cover it pretty well. Basically you get a transaction number in the returned query string which you can then submit back to PayPal to confirm the user hasn't just made it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, the solution is the IPN. Basically, IPN is an url you setup on your merchant account, under selling tools.

1. you would want to create the url that points to your actions. (To do it locally, you would need to do port forwarding to made you site public available)
2. The IPN contains all the information you need. It gets call whenever a payment is been made and it also comes with payment status whether is successful or failed.

Here is a link to there code samples that you can reference to.

https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Update: for details how IPN works behind the scene, reference to the following link

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

Comment: Alright i took a look and implemented the code, but I am still not understanding some things. Is this the what I should put on my page I direct to after there have been redirected to paypal? Currently I have a payment page that has the form on there to submit payment, then I am having it go to the page I put the code sample in, It routes ok, but I am not seeing any usable data there.

Comment: when you say "it routes ok" are you saying it calls your IPN url behind the scene?

Comment: Yeah, the form above, when you click submit it takes you to the paypal sandbox site to sign in and approve the payment. At the end of the process on the paypal site, I click the link that says go back to my site. It will then route to my payment confirm page (where I have the sample code).

Comment: @davidisawesome IPN is "out of band" - it has nothing to do with the user's/browser navigation. Unfortunately, I believe the sample code (at least C#) in the page above is for verifying the POST (already) sent to you. [This link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside) might be better for you to understand IPN more broadly.

Comment: I've added the link to solution for others to reference to

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [PayPal REST API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet) then you can just do:

```
        // You create the ProcessPayment() method
        string jsonResponse = ProcessPayment(model);

        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Payment payment = jss.Deserialize<Payment>(jsonResponse); 

        APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
        Payment originalPayment = Payment.Get(apiContext, payment.id);
```